excel vba web scraping with selenium multiple element problem
I want to scrape a table from chrome in excel vba with selenium, but there are several (currently 2) thead and tbody elements in the class. The code I'm currently using only takes the data from the first thead and tbody . I managed to solve it with Internet Explorer, but it doesn't work with Selenium. Unfortunately, ie is a bit out of date...
the current piece of the page's source code in the image[text]()
Sub test2()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim rowc, cc, columnC As Integer
rowc = 2
driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/argentina/primera-nacional/"

For Each th In driver.FindElementByClass("stats-table-container").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
cc = 1
For Each t In th.FindElementsByTag("th")
Munka1.Cells(22, cc).Value = t.Text
cc = cc + 1
Next t
Next th

For Each tr In driver.FindElementsByClass("stats-table-container").FindElementsByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
columnC = 1
For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
Munka1.Cells(rowc, columnC).Value = td.Text
columnC = columnC + 1
Next td
rowc = rowc + 1
Next tr
'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
End Sub


I tried this as well, but it always throws an error
For Each th In driver.FindElementByClass("stats-table-container").FindElementByTag("thead")(1).FindElementsByTag("tr")

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Use the Inspect menu and get the Full Xpath and then FindByXpath

You need to separate the specification for your second loop, by first finding the body object, and then examining the contents of that. This is because a List element (the tbody element) does not have a child element.
replace this statement:
For Each tr In driver.FindElementsByClass("stats-table-container").FindElementsByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")

with these statements:
Set tb = driver.FindElementByClass("stats-table-container").FindElementByTag("tbody")
For Each tr In tb.FindElementsByTag("tr")

